# How to get AWS config aggregate resources

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-config

I am unable to get AWS Config aggregated discovered resources using Python3 and boto3.

Python=3.7
Boto3=1.9.42
Using AWS SAM to locally test Lambda function but I have the same problem when I run the Lambda within AWS.

```
    client = master_session.client('config', region_name=my_region)

    response = client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources(
        ConfigurationAggregatorName=aggregator,
        ResourceType="AWS::EC2::Instance")
```

Returns error:

```
{
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "errorMessage": "'ConfigService' object has no attribute 'list_aggregate_discovered_resources'",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 41, in lambda_handler\n    r = client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 563, in __getattr__\n    self.__class__.__name__, item)\n"
  ]
}
```

I am however able to run other requests using this client.

This works:

```
response = client.describe_configuration_aggregators()
print("Response: {}".format(response))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the attribute `list_aggregated_discovered_resources` is not supported in the boto3 1.9.42 from below reference.

[ConfigService - Boto3 1.9.42](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_aggregate_discovered_resources)

If you want to use the attribute, then recent version of boto3 is required.